# How to populate a tableview, javafx 8, dynamically

Tags: javafx, tableview

I created a TableView via SceneBuilder so that it receives dynamic data, that is, I will always have distinct SQL scripts whose data I want to display in the TableView.
So the columns are created according to the amount of fields I detect in sql.
This is already being done. The problem is in the code for popular TableView rows.
For this, I get an `ArrayList <String>` with resultSet data, as it is dynamic information,
This `ArrayList <String>` receives each record with the fields separated by #. Then I get the
Number of fields I will have as columns and created TableView columns with similar titles To the field names. That works perfectly.
Then I created a loop to get the `ArrayList <String>` elements, called
Of aListString.At where:
`Data [] []` has the number of rows according to the number of elements of aListString and the quantity Of columns according to the number of fields (qtdeCampos). Until now resolved.
Then the loop fills the array data [] [] without problem, each row with their respective fields.
Finally, I fill out the TableView with:

```
tableViewResultado.getItems().addAll(Arrays.asList(dados));
```

Since the TableView is defined as:

```
@FXML
  private  TableView<String[]> tableViewResultado;
```

However, the rows are not populated with the data data [] [], whose information is correctly Stored in this matrix. The code:

`for(int j=0;j<qtdeCampos;j++)
                {

                    TableColumn<String[],String> column = new TableColumn();
                    column.setText(arrayListCampos.get(j).getNomeCampo());
                    aTableColumn.add(column);
                    tableViewResultado.getColumns().add(column);    
                }
                String dados[][] = new String[aListString.size()][qtdeCampos];
                for(int i=0;i<aListString.size();i++)
                {
                        String dadosX[]=aListString.get(i).split("#");
                        for(int k=0;k<dadosX.length;k++)
                        {
                                dados[i][k]=dadosX[k];
                        }
                }`

Where is the error?
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Can you show the `cellVlaueFactory`s you set on the columns?

Comment: How should I apply this property in my situation?